# Does Selenium suports CRM applications

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

What are the best automation tools which support dynamic Full CRM dynamics application? does Selenium webdriver supports it ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102836/can-we-use-selenium-webdriver-for-automating-ms-crm-2015-based-application

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate as mentioned by JeffC. I have provided my answer there. See if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only test HTML based websites with Selenium. If the CRM application exposes an HTML based front end that is accessible via a web browser then you can use Selenium to test it, if not you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You should check following toolkit from product team based on the Celenium - https://github.com/microsoft/easyrepro

Here is short quote:

> The purpose of this library is to provide Dynamics customers the
>   ability to facilitate automated UI testing for their projects. These
>   API’s provide an easy to use set of commands that make setting up UI
>   testing quick and easy. The functionality provided covers the core CRM
>   commands that end users would perform on a typical workday and working
>   to extend that coverage to more functionality.